# Problems trying to completely remove https text from my Twitter analysis

Tags: r, text-mining, tm

I am trying to analyse >50000 tweets and trying to clean up this data before carrying out any further analysis.

I am using the TM package to clean up my data. I am struggling to remove all URLs, I have remove http urls, but I am left with https URLs. If I try and add a custom remove for these I end up removing the https part and remaining with the remainder of the url (without the forward slashes and punctuations)

```
tweets_corp <- Corpus(VectorSource(the_tweets))
twitterHandleRemover <- function(x) gsub("@\\S+","", x)
urlRemover <- function(x) gsub("http:[[:alnum:]]*","", x)
urlSecond <- function(x) gsub("https:[[:alnum:]]*","" ,x)
hashtagRemover <- function(x) gsub("#\\S+","", x)
cleaner <- function(tweets_corp){
  tweets_corp <- tm_map(tweets_corp, removeNumbers)
  tweets_corp <- tm_map(tweets_corp, content_transformer(urlRemover))
  tweets_corp <- tm_map(tweets_corp, content_transformer(urlSecond))
  tweets_corp <- tm_map(tweets_corp, content_transformer(twitterHandleRemover))
  tweets_corp <- tm_map(tweets_corp, content_transformer(hashtagRemover))
  tweets_corp <- tm_map(tweets_corp, removePunctuation)
  tweets_corp <- tm_map(tweets_corp, content_transformer(tolower))
  return(tweets_corp)
}
```

Here is a sample of my tweets prior to clean up

```
#ignore [example] and []
#SONA2019 #DUTShooting #WitsShutdown https:[example][//t.co]/Dbha6MsWec
```

This is what I am left with

```
tcodbhamswec
```

I have also tried adding this function

```
toSpace = content_transformer(function(x,pattern)gsub(pattern,"",x))
tweets_corp <- tm_map(tweets_corp, toSpace,"(f|ht)tp(s?)://(.*)[.][a-z]+")
```

and end up with this

```
dbhamswec
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve this problem by adding a question mark to my url remover, presumably removing optional space

```
  tweets_corp <- tm_map(tweets_corp, toSpace," ?(f|ht)tp(s?)://(.*)[.][a-z]+")
```